# Coldfusion 10 with apache on Windows Server 2008 R2 x64

Tags: apache, coldfusion, windows-server-2008-r2

I need to deploy another CF 10 server and we want to try out apache instead of IIS and Server 2008 R2 x64 instead of Server 2003. We are limited to Server 2008 R2 because of hardware compatibility with Server 2012. The owner requires we use Windows so no linux.

Does anyone here know of any issues with CF10 on Server 2008 R2 x64 using the apache webserver?

Comment: Have you tried it?  Have you had problems?

Comment: I tried it and had no problems. Just one thing, you cannot use more than Apache 2.2.x and also use the mod_jk given by Adobe. I also observed that the latest ones from Apache site does not work.

Comment: I have not yet tried it. I am still collecting info and I won't be able to retrieve the server from the co-lo until Wednesday so I have a couple of days to test via VM. So what's wrong with apache 2.4?

Answer (score 1):

Officially CF 10 requires Apache 2.2.21. It won't work with Apache 2.4.

Answer (score 0):

We have hosted sites using Cf/Apache on Windows for years, and found it to be a great combination, scaling quite well. We also found that to run CF10, you must run Apache 2.2 or later.